# How to make object null by having only its reference in array?

Tags: java, arrays, object, reference, null

I have an array of game objects in the GameWorld and they can get removed from that world. The problem is that some game objects have references to other game objects. E.g. Player class has a reference to a Bird. Bird gets randomly removed from GameWorld, but Player still has a reference to it. I currently do a null check to check whether the GameObject is still valid and in the world. However, removing an object from the array does not make that reference null. So how can I make it null?

Here is an example:

```
// GameWorld creates bird
ArrayList<Object> gameObjects = new ArrayList<>();
Object bird = new Object();
gameObjects.add(bird);

// Player references it
Object referencedBird = gameObjects.get(0);

// later in GameWorld, another scope, there is no access to the 'bird' object, trying to remove the bird from the world
Object objectToRemove = gameObjects.get(0);
gameObjects.remove(0);
objectToRemove = null;

// back in the Player class
Debug.log("is null " + (referencedBird == null)); // false! I need it to be true
```

Comment: You might want to look at java's [WeakReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)

Answer (score 6):

You can't make an *object* `null`, you can only make a reference `null`. Updating one reference to an object doesn't change other references to the same object.

Think about it like us both having the same person's number in our phones: if I delete the number, it doesn't get deleted from your phone. And if we both delete it, that person's phone number doesn't cease to exist: just neither of us can call them.

The only things you can do are:

- Set `referencedBird = null` explicitly;
- Or refer to it via `gameObjects.get(0)` instead of via the `referencedBird` variable.

Comment: But when there are lots of objects, looping through the whole array and searching for the right object seems inefficient, isn't there a better way?

Comment: You don't need to search if you have the object's index (assuming that they are stored in a `List` which implements `RandomAccess`, like `ArrayList`); or, you could use a `Map<SomeKeyType, Object>` if you don't necessarily want to have to keep all of the "empty" spaces in the list when you null-out an element.

Comment: GameObjects get added and removed quite often, so indices are always shifting, so keeping it wouldn't work

Comment: You can use the `ArrayList` to check if it `contains` `referencedBird ` in the player...instead of checking if `referencedBird ` is `null`

Comment: @boxed__l that is `O(# list elements)`: this is what OP means by "inefficient" in the comment above, I suspect. A `HashMap` is `O(1)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner yeah, making a unique GameObject ID and using it to store in a `Map` sounds quite good

Comment: @AndyTurner Game Object ID would require extra logical (that would pay off eventually)...are you suggesting using the `birdReference`'s as keys in a map? From what I gather, don't `HashSets` (which don't have the added <k,v> complexity) also have O(1) lookups?

Comment: @boxed__l a `HashSet` internally uses a `HashMap`, where the map keys are the values in the set and the map values are arbitrary. But no, I am suggesting a trivially-constructable key (e.g. a `String` or `Integer`).

Answer (score 1):

Okay since Andy pointed out that you can not destroy a object itself you can still have a work-around.

```
 interface RemoveAble<T>{
        boolean isRemoved();
        T prepareRemoveAndGet();
    }

class Bird implements RemoveAble<Bird>{
    boolean shouldRemove = false;
    @Override
    public boolean isRemoved() {
        return shouldRemove;
    }

    @Override
    public Bird prepareRemoveAndGet() {
        shouldRemove = true;
        return this;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
// GameWorld creates bird
ArrayList<RemoveAble> gameObjects = new ArrayList<>();
Bird bird = new Bird();
gameObjects.add(bird);

// Player references it
Bird referencedBird = gameObjects.get(0);

// later in GameWorld, another scope, there is no access to the 'bird' object, trying to remove the bird from the world
Object objectToRemove = gameObjects.get(0).prepareRemoveAndGet;


// back in the Player class
Debug.log("is null " + (referencedBird.isRemoved == true)); // false! I need it to be true
```

And then `null` it by yourself 
e.g.

```
if(referencedBird.isRemoved) referencedBird = null;
```

Comment: @Gintas_ See if its useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to better understand how Java variables work:
I you set a variable to null that does not affect the object behind it at all. You would need to somehow invalidate the referenced object (using a boolean variable) or the better solution would be to always get the object directly from the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike C and C++ in java you cant manipulate memory directly, the only option you have is to remove all the Strong (regular) reference to obj and leave to JVM to remove it from memory whenever it needs memory.

```
    // GameWorld creates bird
    ArrayList<Object> gameObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    Object bird = new Object();
    gameObjects.add(bird);

    // a weak reference to array Item
    WeakReference<Object> referencedBird = new    WeakReference(gameObjects.get(0));
    // manipulating and accessing array item via weak reference
    referencedBird.get().toString();

    // after this remove there is no strong reference to array element (0) and it is available for JVM to revoke
    //memory allocated to it in up-coming garbage collection cycle
    gameObjects.remove(0);

    //garbage collection may remove the obj from memory so this method may return null
    referencedBird.get();
```

Also you have the option to make your  gameObjects list, memory efficient by making array of type WeakReference

```
     ArrayList<WeakReference> weakReferenceToGameObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    Object bird1 = new Object();
    weakReferenceToGameObjects.add((WeakReference) bird1);

    bird1 = null;

    // now if you try to get the element you may get null!
    weakReferenceToGameObjects.get(0).get();
```